# Using the nilness checker for static analysis

Tags: go, static-analysis

I'd like to use the [nilness checker](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools@v0.1.3/go/analysis/passes/nilness) to catch nil pointer dereferences. I installed the checker and built the nilness command:

```
[go]$ ls src/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/nilness/
cmd  nilness.go  nilness_test.go  testdata
[go]$ ls bin/nilness
bin/nilness
[go]$ ls -l bin/nilness
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 ... ... 10291396 Jun 20 22:00 bin/nilness
```

But running `nilness` on a directory or file with known errors produces no output.

As an alternative approach, following the standard guidelines, I created this program:

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/multichecker"
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/loopclosure"
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/nilness"
)

func main() {
    multichecker.Main(
        nilness.Analyzer,
        loopclosure.Analyzer,
    )
}
```

This does not catch nil pointer dereferences either.

Has anybody used this checker? What am I missing?

Comment: It's impossible to help if you don't show us the code you are analyzing.

Comment: Detecting nils with 100% recall and precision is literally impossible on a computer, since it's equivalent to the halting problem. The nilness tool chooses to have 100% precision (ie: no false positives), and so cannot find every nil problem.

Comment: "What am I missing?" The fact what this checker doesn't do. It doesn't run your program und thus doesn't detect nil pointer dereferences detectable only during runtime. It detects nil pointer dereferences detectable during static code analysis (thus not too many).

Comment: To make your question meaningful, you should produce a minimal example that you expect the nil checker to report a problem on and that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work fine. Please double-check the test data on which you are running the `nilness` analyzer.

Let me show you a sample example:

`example/main.go`

```
package nilness

func nilness() {
    var t *int
    if t == nil {
        println(*t) // raise
    }
}
```

`nilness` analyzer (`main.go`)

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/nilness"
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/singlechecker"
)

func main() {
    singlechecker.Main(nilness.Analyzer)
}
```

Run:

```
$ go build -o checker
$ ./checker ./...
```

Output:

```
<path>/example/main.go:5:7: tautological condition: nil == nil
<path>/example/main.go:6:11: nil dereference in load
```

As @Volker already pointed out that the `nilness` analyzer only detects the statically provable nil pointer references in your program, so there are usually very less. Maybe this is the reason it is not working for you.